# Dynamic array challenge

Tags: java, programming-challenge

It solves the problem listed [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array). How can I make this more efficient?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static int getIndex(int x, int lastAns,Integer size) {
        return ((x ^ lastAns) % size);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int q = in.nextInt();

    LinkedList<Integer>[] sequenceList = new LinkedList[n];
    int lastAns = 0;
    while(q-- != 0) {
        int queryType = in.nextInt();
        int x = in.nextInt();
        int y = in.nextInt();
        int index = getIndex(x, lastAns, n);
        if(queryType == 1) {
            if(sequenceList[index] == null) sequenceList[index] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            sequenceList[index].add(y);
        } else if(queryType == 2) {
            lastAns = sequenceList[index].get(y % sequenceList[index].size());
            System.out.println(lastAns);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Include the problem statement into your question's body.

Comment: @denis It solves the problem listed here is the link, highlighted. Mentioned just before the code. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When instancing generic collections, it' best to use the diamond operator to let the compiler figure out the generic arguments. This lets you define in a single place (type definition, not constructor) for easier future modification.

   sequenceList[index] = new LinkedList<>();
2. When using an Object, always declare its type as the highest class in its type hierarchy (up to interface if possible).

You're not using LinkedList's specific methods, so:

```
List<Integer>[] sequenceList = new List[n];
```

3. Javadoc!
4. Use proper Objects:

   - Make Solution a real instance created one in `main` (no real job should be performed in `main`). Then you can make `lastAns` and `n` fields of `Solution` because in the problem statement it is made to be a *state* of the Solution, so you don't need to pass those around every time
   - You could Wrap your `List`s in a `Sequence` internal class of `Solution`. Internal means it will be able to access the `lastAns` field of the `Solution` instance etc.
5. It's a bit weird to lazily initialize the sequences. You don't win much, but you put an ugly if in your code. If there is no risk having a huge but sparse array, I would drop this.
6. Don't one-line `if`s, and always use brackets
7. I'm usually against calling variables `x`, `y` etc. On this case it's defined in the problem so it's ok.

---

Updated code:

```
public class Solution {
    private int n;
    private int q;
    private int lastAns = 0;
    public Solution(int size, int numberOfQuestions) {
        n = size;
        q = numberOfQuestions;
    }
    public int getIndex(int x) {
        return (x ^ lastAns) % n;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Solution solution = new Solution(in.nextInt(), in.nextInt());
        solution.solve(in);
    }
    public void solve(Scanner in) {
        List<Integer>[] sequenceList = new List[n];
        while(q-- != 0) {
            int queryType = in.nextInt();
            int x = in.nextInt();
            int y = in.nextInt();
            int index = getIndex(x);
            if(queryType == 1) {
                if(sequenceList[index] == null) {
                    sequenceList[index] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                }
                sequenceList[index].add(y);
            } else if(queryType == 2) {
                lastAns = sequenceList[index].get(y % sequenceList[index].size());
                System.out.println(lastAns);
            }
        }
    }
}
```